# Error when calling function in twig, Call to a member function render() on null, twig extension

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, twig-extension

I have a problem using the function as a servis in a twig swatch.
I would like to inject some of the template into the page, in part it goes wrong because the page loads but in the place where it should be injected the template pops up error

> Error: Call to a member function render() on null

This is a function to be called in the page

```
public function printCategoriesList() {

    $categoryRepo = $this->doctrine->getRepository('AirblogBundle:Category');
    $categoriestList = $categoryRepo->findAll();

    return $this->environment->render(
                    'AirblogBundle:Template:categoriesList.html.twig', ['categoriesList' => $categoriestList]
    );
}
```

Below is a link to the rest of the file

[Plunker Files](http://plnkr.co/edit/e4dubXWofNgUd9b2T9bZ?p=preview)

I work on symfony version 2.8

Comment: Looking at the files there are some fundamental things missing.  You are using `environment` as a class variable without properly injecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the initRuntime function from TwigExtension and try this:

```
public function printCategoriesList(\Twig_Environment $environment) {

    $categoryRepo = $this->doctrine->getRepository('AirblogBundle:Category');
    $categoriestList = $categoryRepo->findAll();

    return $environment->render(
                    'AirblogBundle:Template:categoriesList.html.twig', ['categoriesList' => $categoriestList]
    );
}
```

Comment: I've already tried it and it shows an error:  An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AirblogBundle\Twig\Extension\BlogExtension::printCategoriesList() must be an instance of Twig_Environment, none given, called in C:\wamp64\www\airblog\app\cache\dev\classes.php on line 5305 and defined").

Comment: Hmm confusing. I tried it on my project and it worked instantly. Can you provide your whole Twig_Extension file with this version?

Comment: Follow this implemetation: http://www.lrotherfield.com/blog/symfony2-get-twig-environment-twig-extension

Comment: I checked this blog and it also did not work. Below is an Extension file that extends the class http://plnkr.co/edit/maFoKBlLiIiSnuafMGQ3?p=preview

Comment: Ok now it works :) Just need to add \  printCategoriesList(\Twig_Environment $env) Thank you Rawburner for the tips